# How do I make an object emit from different points, and animate the emission location?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials

I have made these objects in 3D. I would like to bounce random balls of light around inside them so that they collide between surfaces like they are inside a pinball machine.  I would like them to emit light which glows and flickers from within at random points across the vertices if possible.

[image: target object for the emission material]

Comment: Can you show your 3D mesh model in the Blender 3D View window?  Consider using Blender Particles.  Your question is difficult to understand.  Please place the most important information at the beginning of your question.

Comment: I would like a glow to pass across the surface. Not from an external light if possible, but an internal glow. I am basically asking if you can animate the properties of a material across the surface. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would also like to fire emitting balls of light around inside them, or to spin this set up through 90 degrees and drop balls through the inside of the object using gravity

Comment: Dave, update your question to be more specific, don't keep important info in the comments.

Comment: You could create a particle system that emits from the volume of the mesh and use a dupli object such as a sphere with an emission shader for the particles.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Particle System and use either the Dynamic Paint or the Point Density in Cycles. Both can create exacly what you want with some additional Material tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use two different procedural textures and mix then with a color mix nodes. To make them flicker you can use the following driver on the mix factor field:

## abs(sin(frame/12))

Comment: thanks procedural textures is really good, but I want them to animate across the surface. is that possible?

Comment: tell me how I can get the current frame number in Cycles Material Nodes and I'll be conviced.